# How to pass one function as an argument into another function in C++?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

Functions are said to be first class objects in C++.
How is it possible to replicate the following pyhton code in C++?

```
def print_wrapper(a):
    print(a)

def execute_function(func, arg):
    return func(arg)

execute_function(print_wrapper, 'test_argument')
```

Please note that the function `print_wrapper` is passed as an argument into the function `execute_function`.

Comment: Search for terms like "functor", "function object", "std::function", "function pointer" and "lambda function".

Comment: looks like preprocessor task, `#define  print_wrapper(a)   print(a)` or `#define execute_function(func, arg) func(arg)`

Comment: @SHR - No, no, definitely not!